# Animation effects in tabBarController:didSelectViewController:

Tags: animation

Within my:

```
- (void )tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
                          didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)thisViewController
{
     [self doAnimationForView:thisViewController.view];
}
```

This delegate method is being called as it should be, EXCEPT for the very first click of a UITabBarItem .. subsequent clicks do call this method, but not the first.

I am aware of this in the Apple docs ...

> For iOS ≥ v3.0, the tab bar controller calls this method even if the
>   selected view controller hasn't changed. NOTE: we are not called when
>   our code changes the tab bar contents programmatically.
>
> For iOS < 3.0, this method is called only when the selected view
>   controller changes. But, the method is called for programmatic changes
>   to the selected view controller.

I need some help to unravel this mystery.

Thanks,

Comment: You can and should post your solution as an answer to this question(which you can accept later).

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than ruining the original question with an answer edit! I've rolled back your edit.